# Disable downloading system updates by default in Android

Tags: nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat

Yesterday got a notification on Nexus 4 saying system update available "Kit kat (Android 4.4)"
Have waited for the download to complete but showed a message "Verfication failed" and "Check Now" button at the button.

Clicked "Check Now" button and it started the download again, it happened a couple of times and really irritating that it tries to download update from the beginning every time.

Now, as not sure what's the problem, want to try updating to kitkat version after a couple of days and want to disable auto-download for now. Is there any way to disable auto-download of system updates or any one else faced this problem?

Comment: Have you rooted your phone or installed a custom recovery?

Comment: No. It came with Android 4.2 and upgraded to 4.3 earlier and haven't faced this issue.